# How can i show All Children product even if it is outofstock in Bundle Product?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have one Bundle product with 3 child product.One child product is out of stock. Now My bundle product shows only 2 child products.But i need to show all child products even if it is in Zero QTY. Where i can edit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I am asking which core file i have to edit?

Comment: Yes, but that's not a programming question. That's a look up the documentation or turn on the developer debug options in Magento. Once you know the file then you could come here with the code and ask for help when you get stuck.

Comment: app\code\core\Mage\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php

Comment: $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
        true        
        //Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
        );

Comment: Any way Thanks for your clarification about this question. Here after i will post question like this in magento.stackexchange.com